# prefixtext visible after tap on TextFormField else an empty space

Tags: flutter

i added a prefixtext in the TextFormField with the hint text but hint text is visible but onplace of prefixtext a empty space is visible,prefixtext visible only when we tap on the textformfield

```
Widget _textField(String text, TextEditingController controller,
      {bool enable = true, TextInputType keyboardType, int maxLength}) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: TextFormField(
            inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxLength),
            ],
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              prefixText: maxLength == 10 ? "+91  " : null,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
              hintText: text,
            ),
            enabled: enable,
            controller: controller,
            keyboardType: keyboardType,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the prefixIcon is always visible

```
prefixIcon: SizedBox(
                    child: Center(
                      widthFactor: 0.0,
                      child: Text('+91'),
                    ),
                  ),
```